# Ansible: Need help in manipulating with date and time

Tags: ansible

Example:

```
12:02:43.569 UTC Wed Jul 06 2022
```

I wish to get an ansible script to go back 15 minutes from the above timing

```yaml
---
 - name: Cisco NXOS
   hosts: all
   connection: network_cli
   gather_facts: false
   vars:
     - cmdlist1: sh clock 
     - ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
     - ansible_network_os: nxos
     - cmdlist2: sh logging | include 2/3

   tasks:
     - name: Execute command
       nxos_command:
        commands: "{{ cmdlist1 }}"
       register: output
     - set_fact:
         arr: "{{ output.stdout_lines[0][1].split() }}"
     - debug:
          msg: "{{ arr[0] }}"
```

Tried my code after @vladimir suggested a working code

```yaml
---
 - name: Cisco NXOS
   hosts: all
   connection: network_cli
   gather_facts: false
   vars:
     - cmdlist1: sh clock 
     - ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
     - ansible_network_os: nxos
     - cmdlist2: sh logging | include 2/3

   tasks:
     - name: Execute command
       nxos_command:
        commands: "{{ cmdlist1 }}"
       register: output
     - set_fact:
         arr: "{{ output.stdout_lines[0][1] }}"
     - debug:
         msg: | 
            {{ arr }}
            {{ t1 }} 
            {{ t2 }} 
            {{ t3 }}
         
       vars:
          t1: "{{ (arr|to_datetime('%H:%M:%S.%f %Z %a %b %d %Y')).strftime('%s') }}"
          t2: "{{ t1|int - 15 * 60 }}"
          t3: "{{ '%H:%M:%S %Z %a %b %d %Y'|strftime(t2) }}
```

output :

```
[LABPC@lab-jump-host dow]$ ansible-playbook interfaceflappingdup.yml -i inventory1.txt --limit nxos -verbose
```

Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

```yaml
PLAY [Cisco NXOS] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Execute command] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos] => {"changed": false, "stdout": ["Time source is NTP\n19:53:30.797 UTC Wed Jul 06 2022"], "stdout_lines": [["Time source is NTP", "19:53:30.797 UTC Wed Jul 06 2022"]]}

TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos] => {"ansible_facts": {"arr": "19:53:30.797 UTC Wed Jul 06 2022"}, "changed": false}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos] => {
    "msg": "19:53:30.797 UTC Wed Jul 06 2022\n1657151610 \n1657150710 \n19:38:30 EDT Wed Jul 06 2022\n"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
nxos                       : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

below are the questions from my output

1. strftime('%s') n t1 variable represents converting everything into epochtime seconds?
2. t3 variable converting epochtime into normal format?
3. my debug output prints everything with \n.I have tried to remove it. unfortunately, it s not getting removed (my ansible.cfg s not editable as it s restricted to be edited ). plz help me out.
4. The converted output after subtracting 15 mins, it gives output n EDT..can i plz get it n UTC itself.

Comment: Post the Ansible code how did you get the date and time.

Comment: @VladimirBotka  thanks for the response..plz find the updated question with script

Comment: Open new questions and focus on single problems. Make the questions [mre].

Comment: @VladimirBotka   sure..thanks for the tip..I ll post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, neglecting microseconds,

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      {{ arr.0 }}
      {{ t1 }}
      {{ t2 }}
      {{ t3 }}
  vars:
    t1: "{{ (arr.0|to_datetime('%H:%M:%S.%f %Z %a %b %d %Y')).strftime('%s') }}"
    t2: "{{ t1|int - 15 * 60 }}"
    t3: "{{ '%H:%M:%S %Z %a %b %d %Y'|strftime(t2) }}"
```

gives

```
msg:
  12:02:43.569 UTC Wed Jul 06 2022
  1657101763
  1657100863
  11:47:43 UTC Wed Jul 06 2022
```

See [Handling dates and times](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times).

Comment: ..thanks again..tried my code as above..updated n the main content